# Resize the image user inputted into the ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

So I have an ImageView which will retrieve the image from the database to show it on the program. However, I want the image retrieved to be resized to a specific height and width (thus it shall not fill the whole screen)

I want it's width to be 150dp, whereas its height to be 230dp.

However, the image that is in the database may be null, and as such, we can not set the ImageView's height and width, else there will be empty space on the layout.

So, how can I resize the image?

Following are my current codes:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/Img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use scale type fitXY

```
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/Img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to use Picasso, you can easily resize your image like this:

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(image)
    .resize(150, 230)
    .into(imageView);
```

There are many other possibilities, you can check it here:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Answer (score 0):

First create values in your dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="imageview_width">150dp</dimen> 
<dimen name="imageview_height">230dp</dimen>
```

Then, in your code where you handle the images received from the db:

```
if(image != null){
    imageview.getLayoutParams().height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageview_height);
    imageview.getLayoutParams().width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageview_width);
    imageview.setimagedrawable(img); // or any way that suits you.
    }
```

This way you can translate the dp values to pixel values and can change the imageview size programmatically after it was inflated from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure to understand your needs. But if you want a view to resize to 150x230 you need to use rajahsekar's answers. But if you also want your Imaview to take no place if the Image is null in DB you can set programatically :

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```